# What is the Kernel of $\omega$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm totally confused about the concept of kernel, could someone help me solve this?

Suppose that $\omega(\begin{bmatrix}j&k\\l&m\end{bmatrix})=(j+k)+(j+l)x+(j+m)x^2$. What is the Kernel of $\omega$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems $\omega$ is a map $\omega: \mathrm{Mat}_{2\times 2}\to P^2$, so a $2\times 2$ matrix is mapped on a polynomial of (at most) degree 2. To find the kernel, you have to find all such matrices which are mapped onto the null polynomial. So every coefficient has to be zero.

So $j+k=0$ and $j+l=0$ and $j+m=0$, which gives $j=-k=-l=-m$.

So every matrix of the form $\begin{pmatrix}j&-j\\-j&-j\end{pmatrix}$ is an element of the kernel of $\omega$.